Accessing my rest api in spring from react native mobile app getting -> [AxiosError: Network Error]
I am trying to access my rest api in spring from my mobile app developed in react native, it works fine when my app is started on android emulator in Android studio, this is code example:
`async function onClick() {
console.log('kliik');
const config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://10.0.2.2:8080/api/authentication/login',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  },
  data: {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
  },
};
console.log(config.url);
try {
  await axios(config).then((resp: any) => {
    console.log(resp.data);
  });

} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error initiating:', error);
}
}

`
But when I run app on my android device I am getting error " Error initiating: [AxiosError: Network Error]" .
I changed ip address from 10.0.2.2 to ip address of machine where server is runnnig, and added in AndroidManifest.xml
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
in application tag and added
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
Phone and machine where server is running are in same network.

I know it's not a valid solution but I deleted node_modules folder and did npm install  and it started to work all by itself

In the catch, use console.log(error.response) to get more information about the error, such as status code and response details.
